# Getting current log directory in a CPP Node

Tags: ros-humble, logging, rclcpp, logger

I have a different process in my CPP node that writes a separate log file.

Right now, this log is written to a file in `ros2_ws/log/additional_process.log` but I would like to put that file in the specific ROS log folder of that run, e.g. `ros2_ws/log/build_2023-10-09_8-51-26/additional_process.log`.

Does anyone know how to get the specific run/build directory in CPP for every run/launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question as follows:

- You know how to specify a custom log folder,
- You have folders `build`, `install` and `log` from running `colcon build` in your `ros2_ws` workspace,
- You currently specify `ros2_ws/log/` as log folder,
- However, you would like to log to the the latest build directory for your workspace instead (e.g. `ros2_ws/log/build_2023-10-09_8-51-26/`).

If this is correct, then the answer is to simply specify `ros2_ws/log/latest` or `ros2_ws/log/latest_build` as log directory, as these `latest` and `latest_build` are symbolic links to the latest build directory.

I'm not sure though what you mean with "get the specific run/build directory in CPP". In any case: you can retrieve the log folder through `rcl_logging_get_logging_directory()` or [`rclcpp::get_logging_directory()`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/77c7aaf9178268c16dee8fc412537e9f67d2afe1/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/logger.cpp#L57).

Comment: Thank you! Adding something to the `ros2_ws/log/latest` solved the problem! The `rclcpp::get_loggin_directory()` returned `~/.ros/log/` which I did not intend to use.